# Where does firefox save/store auto fill data

Tags: firefox, passwords, autocomplete

where does firefox store passwords and username when we opt for remember password. Is it always cookies or some other encrypted file.Also where is the data filled by auto complete functionality of browsers come from. It doesn't seem to come from cookies as same auto-complete info sometimes appears in fields of websites other than those it was previously filled in. Is it possible to retrieve data from browser itself(sensitive as well as the general one)?

Answer (score 1):

you can see saved passwords (depending on OS) in the options/preferences under security - saved passwords. Saved passwords are stored in a `hidden folder` `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\(X#X#X#X#X#X#X).default` where X#X#X#X#X# is unique. They are the `key3.db` file and the `signings.sqlite` file

Comment: well that sounds depressing what about windows XP SP3? Can you tell me a way to turn it off?

Comment: Put a master password on or don't save passwords

Comment: @Raystafarian AFAIR the master password only protects the stored passwords, not the saved general form data.

Comment: @Robert that is correct. My answer only addressed 1 part of the question, which doesn't make it much of an answer, but it's more than a comment.